Deciphering a birthplace in an 1850 marriage record in Hungary
Does anyone by any chance recognize this placename? It's from an 1850 marriage in Pest, where it is recorded as the birthplace of a 27-year-old groom (third entry on page: https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-CSLR-P7X2-1).

Transcription of entry: 
Delbeck Péter, és Szeitl Katalin R.C. 
nőtelen Mázoló [placename goes here]i szül, kisded korátol itenni K.l.v.?. 27. éves, Hajadon Pesti szül k.l.v: 22. éves. 
Rupp Sebestyén Bormérő és Romhányi Alajos Rézműves 
Szlatky Károly Káplán
(Which is: 
Groom and bride: Péter Delbeck and Katalin Szeitl, Roman Catholics. 
Status, birthplace and residence: single [house-]painter of [...] birth, here since infancy, has baptismal certificate, age 27 years; single, of Pest birth, has baptismal certificate, age 22 years. 
Witnesses: Sebestyén Rupp, wine-tapster and Alajos Romhányi coppersmith. 
Officiant: Károly Szlatky curate.)

I Comment only to commend you and anyone who could decipher any such scribble. Wow!

Someone on a Hungarian genealogy forum figured it out: it's Penzing, district 14 of Vienna.
(Now to figure out the groom's father's [also named Peter Delbeck] place of origin... His marriage record in 1814 appears to say something about France, a daughter's birth record in 1821 appears to mention the Netherlands, and both may say something about "Namur", which is in Belgium.)
